# Have you seen an issue in which bazel query returns no results on first run and then works correctly if repeated?

Tags: bazel

I'm running a command that looks like this (replacing actual rule name with "abc"):

```
bazel query --output=xml --xml:default_values 'kind("abc rule", //...)'
```

The first time it runs without any working tree (e.g., after `bazel clean --expunge`), it always yields no results. There are no errors or warnings either. What I mean is that it runs for several minutes loading packages and then doesn't print any XML or other output.

Then I run the *exact same* query a second time, and it spits out the expected XML. From then on, even if the source changes, it continues working. If I clear the cache again, the same behavior repeats itself.

There is literally nothing that changes between the two commands. The second one runs quickly and works fine.

**Has anyone else experienced this? Any idea what might be causing it?**

The purpose of this query, in case it isn't obvious, is to find all occurrences of a particular rule (one defined by me) within a source tree that contains several BUILD files. I haven't tried other queries to see if they exhibit similar behavior.

Comment: I tried this with bazel 3.4.1, and I'm no longer able to reproduce the issue. Hopefully that means it's resolved.

Comment: Correction: The problem still exists on 3.4.1, but I'm unable to reproduce it (so far at least) on master/HEAD.